# Use both preact-cli@2.2.1 and preact-cli@3.0.0

Tags: version, preact

I have installed preact-cli@2.2.1 with

```
npm install -g preact-cli
```

Works fine. Now I want to use preact-cli@3.0.0 without changing the old version. I tried:

```
md pwa10
cd pwa10
npm install preact-cli@3.0.0-rc.4
```

Looks good. Then:

```
preact info
```

shows version 2.2.1, not as expected 3.0.0. How can I use the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2.2.1 installed globally, and 3.0.0 installed locally to your project. Local packages are not added to your machine's PATH - you have to run them directly from `node_modules`.

Alternatively, you could create an [NPM script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) that calls `preact` - local packages *are* available in the PATH in that context.